# How to use a plugin's directive in a functional component - Vue 2

Tags: vue.js

There's a plugin: https://vuejs-tips.github.io/vue-the-mask/

And a functional component:

```js
import { mask } from 'vue-the-mask'

const component = createElement('input', {
  directives: [
    name: 'v-mask'
  ]
})
```

How to actually apply this mask to my functional component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to hardcode directive:

```js
const component = createElement('input', {
  directives: [
    name: 'mask',
    value: '##-##-##',
  ]
})
```

If you just want to pass it down through component, like: `<InputBox v-mask="'##-##-##'" />`:

```js
const component = createElement('input', {
  ...(data.directives?.length && {
    directives: [data.directives[0]],
  }),
})
```

It would accept just one directive, if you want to use multiple directives, then you just need to loop through them.